# Spring-Boot multiple db target dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot

Is there a 'community/Spring' approved method with Boot to have different datasource target for the same project?

Should I include both connector (H2 and Mysql) in the project dependencies and just change the jdbc url in my `application.yml`?

We are switching our tomcat instance to a Boot project, old habits of having jdbc jar as provided. I was wondering if this was still supported or desired in a boot fat jar/war exec.

Comment: Why do you need to include both? How do you intend to, once you have compiled the Boot artefact, switch between them?

Comment: Yes I intent to switch between them. Right now the package has both h2 and mysql connector jars. I was wondering if this was a bad thing ...

Comment: But _how_? That was my question. If you want to switch on the same compiled artefact, I would recommend the usage of [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles) to manage the connection settings. Otherwise, I would say use [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to select the appropriate setup at compile time.

Comment: Include both drivers. Point the default to production in your `application.yml` add an `application-dev.yml` and when using a dev machine launch with `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`. Which would then use the jdbc url for H2 instead of MySQL. You can still use auto configuration with that. You just need to configure the proper datasource properties/urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood Your question correctly, there are two scenarios, that You could be intrested in.

First is where You use both datasources at once in your project (ex. getting data from both H2 and MySQL in the same time, or one after another).

Second scenario is when You use two datasources but not at once, for example: H2 for test/debug project build, MySQL for production. Another sub-scenario is like You want something like primary/secondary datasources.

Solution for first scenario is to add two dependencies, disable Boot autoconfiguration (autoconfiguration won't work for multiple datasources) for databases and manually configure tho separate EntityManagers etc. (more info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-two-entity-managers)

Sorry that I can't provide any code sample but I can't access my work repo from home.

Moving to the second scenario what You can do is, use profiles.
You have to create separate profile and application-something.yml file for that profile. Inside you configure your second datasource, and then in dependencies you can make your second database dependency to add only with specific profile as well - but here im not 100% sure, I don't remember how we did it in work ;d.

And again, I cant paste any example but here is some help:
[Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles), 
[Profile-specific configuration files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

An then there is a sub-scenario that I mentioned earlier. Marking datasource as `@Primary` But here I've never used it, I just know it exists: [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources)

Edit2: After some rethinking, I think this is the way to go with Boot and active profiles: [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html)

Sorry for a lot of spam, and reconsiderations. That was quite confusing for sure.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Should this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200232/spring-boot-how-to-configure-multiple-datasources/32414138#32414138