# How to change JdbcTemplate name?

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

In my application multiple data source have been configured, so need to create jdbcTemplate in a different name. I am getting exception when changing the jdbcTemplate name

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="reportsViewTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="edao" class="com.myapp.dao.EmployeeDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate1" ref="reportsViewTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

In My DAO

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate1 = jdbcTemplate;
}
```

getting the below exception when trying to change the name

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'edao' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jdbcTemplate1' of bean class [com.myapp.dao.EmployeeDao]: Bean property 'jdbcTemplate1' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'jdbcTemplate'?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.myapp.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)
```

I want to change the name from jdbcTemplate to any other name.How can I achieve that?

Comment: For the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200232/spring-boot-how-to-configure-multiple-datasources

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you havnt changed jdbcTemplate property name to jdbcTemplate 1 , at all the places.
Please recheck or share changed xml and java file.

Comment: I have changed the name

Comment: change the setter name to setJdbcTemplate1, also add similar getter.