# springboot how to dynamically switch different datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, datasource

I have the requirement like to switch the `datasource` at runtime. The different database configuration data(it may be mysql, oracle, mongodb ..) is persisted in DB. Because I need to add `datasource` at any time, so I do that. Now, when I use the `datasource`, I will get database configuration data in the DB and create a new `sqlSessionFactory` again.

How can I give it to Spring IOC container to deal with?

Comment: Could you give specific example that causes you any specific trouble?

Comment: Use a custom scope and an `interface` proxy. When you need to change, simply destroy the old instance in the scope and set the new one.

Comment: See the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41563065/4423636

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need supported by Spring multitenancy.

You need to define tenant resolver to identify which tenant you need (e.g. by intercepting request and get tenant from header or from token), tenant context to keep tenant (e.g. a ThreadLocal storage where tenant is defined for each thread) and multitenant connection provider (which read tenant from thread local and provide DataSource/connection specific for the tenant).

See [the example](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation) and [the example](https://www.ricston.com/blog/multitenancy-jpa-spring-hibernate-part-1/)

Comment: It's a bit similar,but the example is unspecific . In addition, a tenant maybe have a multiple datasource. The datasource maybe is nosql